# How do I make a time sequence?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have assistance in adding an automatic sequence to my code.  I would appreciate any form of help towards this task, and I would greatly appreciate it if the question was done for me.
Here is the traffic light array I have done so far:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<img id="img" src="./Programming/images/Traffic light 1.jpg"/>
</body>
<button onclick="changingimg()" type="button">Click Here!</button>

<script>

var array = [
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 1.jpg",
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 2.jpg",
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 3.jpg"];
var arrayindex = 0;
var arraylength= array.length;
function changingimg(){
         document.getElementById('img').src = array[arrayindex]
                  if(arrayindex == (arraylength-1)){
                  arrayindex=0;}
                  else{++arrayindex;}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: put `setTimeout(changingimg, 2000)` at the end of changingimg()

Comment: I would simplify the function as `function changingimg(){
         document.getElementById('img').src = array[arrayindex++ % arraylength];
}`

Answer (score 0):

It would even be a good idea to use `getElementById` just once (if loaded) then in the end I would write it

```
var array = [
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 1.jpg",
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 2.jpg",
    "./Programming/images/Traffic light 3.jpg"],
    arrayindex = 0,
    arraylength= array.length,
    img = document.getElementById('img'),
    interval = 2000;
setTimeout(function (){
      img.src = array[arrayindex++ % arraylength];
}, interval);
```